# Invalid object name when trying to add new items

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following classes generated by the Reverse engineering tool (Entity Framework Power Tools):

[image: The db schema]

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Areas = new List<Area>();
        this.Areas1 = new List<Area>();
        this.Areas2 = new List<Area>();
        this.Areas3 = new List<Area>();
        this.Companies = new List<Company>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveDirectory { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
    public bool AllAreas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas3 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public Area()
    {
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }

    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string AreaNL { get; set; }
    public string AreaFR { get; set; }
    public string ExternalID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int AreaManagerID { get; set; }
    public int DistrictManagerID { get; set; }
    public int VAID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And the constructors of the mapping files:

```
    public UserMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.UserID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.Login)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.Password)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.Language)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(2);

        this.Property(t => t.Email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("AreaManager");
        this.Property(t => t.UserID).HasColumnName("UserID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.Login).HasColumnName("Login");
        this.Property(t => t.Password).HasColumnName("Password");
        this.Property(t => t.ActiveDirectory).HasColumnName("ActiveDirectory");
        this.Property(t => t.Language).HasColumnName("Language");
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(t => t.ValidFrom).HasColumnName("ValidFrom");
        this.Property(t => t.ValidTo).HasColumnName("ValidTo");
        this.Property(t => t.AllAreas).HasColumnName("AllAreas");
    }

    public AreaMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.AreaID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.AreaNL)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.AreaFR)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.ExternalID)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Area");
        this.Property(t => t.AreaID).HasColumnName("AreaID");
        this.Property(t => t.AreaNL).HasColumnName("AreaNL");
        this.Property(t => t.AreaFR).HasColumnName("AreaFR");
        this.Property(t => t.ExternalID).HasColumnName("ExternalID");
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyID).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
        this.Property(t => t.AreaManagerID).HasColumnName("AreaManagerID");
        this.Property(t => t.DistrictManagerID).HasColumnName("DistrictManagerID");
        this.Property(t => t.VAID).HasColumnName("VAID");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.Users)
            .WithMany(t => t.Areas3)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("UserArea");
                    m.MapLeftKey("AreaID");
                    m.MapRightKey("UserID");
                });

        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.Areas)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.AreaManagerID);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Company)
            .WithMany(t => t.Areas)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyID);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User1)
            .WithMany(t => t.Areas1)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DistrictManagerID);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User2)
            .WithMany(t => t.Areas2)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.VAID);

    }
```

Now if I try to do the following:

```
        using (var ctx = new FCTestContext())
        {
            // Step 1: add user
            var user = new User
            {
                ActiveDirectory = false,
                Login = "Joske",
                Email = "tst@abc.com",
                Password = "sdfsdff",
                Name = "JoskeVermeulen",
                Language = "NL"
            };

            // Step 2: add an Area

            Company company = new Company { Active = true, CompanyName = "CompanyTest" };

            Area area = new Area
            {
                AreaFR = "Anvers",
                AreaNL = "Antwerpen",
                Company = company,
                User = user
            };
            ctx.Areas.Add(area);


            try
            {
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (DbValidationError validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        //Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName,
                                          validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                for (Exception eCurrent = ex; eCurrent != null; eCurrent = eCurrent.InnerException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(eCurrent.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

It gives me the error:

Invalid object name dbo.AreaManager. I have clearly not that table and also not the intent on adding it. I should only provide the 3 foreign keys for each manager one and a user should also be able to see all areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just after jotting everything down and going over the code again after posting one sees where the culprit is :-(.

It's in the line

```
this.ToTable("AreaManager");
```

For some reason the tools have generated it like that to be mapped as such in the database. Changing it to

```
this.ToTable("User");
```

Made it work.

Comment: I'm going to figure out why it was generated like that. When I find it I'll update the reply. In the mean time if someone has the same thing happening or knows why please comment as well.